# wglGetProcAddress is undefined

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013, glfw, glew

I'm following [this](https://open.gl/context) OpenGL tutorial but I'm stuck on linking libraries.

```
#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <thread>


typedef void (*GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS) wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);


    glfwTerminate();
}
```

For some reason function `wglGetProcAddress` is undefined. These are the libs I linked: glew32.lib, glew32s.lib, glfw3.lib, opengl32.lib.

MSDN [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that `wglGetProcAddress` is included in opengl32.lib. What am I doing wrong?

> Error  1   error C3861: 'wglGetProcAddress': identifier not found  e:\workspaces\visual studio\learningopengl1\learningopengl1\main.cpp    32  1   LearningOpenGl1
>
> 2   IntelliSense: identifier "wglGetProcAddress" is undefined   e:\Workspaces\Visual Studio\LearningOpenGl1\LearningOpenGl1\main.cpp    34  41  LearningOpenGl1

Comment: Linking isn't the only issue, you also need to include the correct header. When I checked Google it said the function is defined in Wingdi.h.

Comment: This generates a few hundred errors (mostly missing ';').

Comment: The tutorial says do not run this code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a linker error, this is a compiler error - so the libraries you link do not matter at this stage at all.

Your compiler is telling you that it doesn't know `wglGetProcAddress`, because it never saw a declaration for this. Your compiler should also not know `GENBUFFERS`, as this type is not defined anywhere either. In the [official `glext.h` file](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glext.h), the type you are looking for is called `PFNGLGENBUFFERS`.

If you really want to manually use the `wgl` API, you probably should include `GL/gl.h` along with the latest `glext.h`and use the correct type names.

The big question to me is: What you are trying to do at all here? You are including `glew.h`, which is a library those sole purpose is to do the GL function pointer queries for you. All you need to do is calling `glewInit()` and you're done (well, don't forget to set `glewExperimental=GL_TRUE` before in a core profile, since GLEW is broken and won't work without that in core profiles). No need to mess with `wglGetProcAddress()` manually at all.

Furthermore, you are also using GLFW. So if you manually want to query the function pointers, you would be best of using GLFW's abstraction of the platform specific pointer query APIs, which would be `glfwGetProcAddress()`, and should at already be declared - again no need to mess with `wglGetProcAddress()`.